# How to change a URL without reloading the page in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, fragment-identifier

Is it possible to change the URL without reloading the page in ASP.net?

Answer (score 3):

In versions of HTML prior to 5 (so XHTML, HTML4 etc), it is not possible to manipulate the actually whole url of the page, but you do so via the fragment identifier as @JamesGoodwin has said. This is used to great effect on Facebook, Twitter etc.

In HTML 5, an API has been designed that allows you to push history changes which reflect the actual URL of the page. A great example of this is when navigating the source tab on Github.

Here is a [rundown of the API at the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history)

Answer (score 1):

The only part of the URL you can change without reloading the page is the [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier).

The fragment identifier can be changed by modifying the `location.hash` property using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

i think you can do this with javascript. try this:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

Comment: this will reload the page